# What is the correct way to capture variables for direct call rules?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

What is the correct way to declare variables for direct call rules so that I can capture it in DTM?

For example I have a page where I want to record a pageview because the DOM hasn't changed in the page so I will be using DTM to call "ajaxPage" to get the value of form_name and put it in an eVar1. Is it version 1 or version 2?

Version 1:

```
_satellite.track('ajaxPage');
var form_name = 'contact-search';
```

Version 2

```
var form_name = 'contact-search';
_satellite.track('ajaxPage');
```

Comment: I feel like this is some kind of trick question or maybe you aren't explaining it enough... at face value, if you want to reference a variable in your code, it needs to exist So, version 2 would be correct..

Comment: things to consider: if you are calling that within an ajax callback, then `form_name` is scoped to that callback, and DTM won't see it. You will need to set it to global (`window`) scope. Alternatively, set an adhoc data element  `_satellite.setVar('form_name','contact-search');` and then use `_satellite.getVar('form_name')` or `%form_name%` in DTM, depending on how you are setting `eVar1`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand the use case but Direct Call rules are used when you need to "force" analytics to be sent on an action that cannot be captured by a typical page load rule or event-based rules (clicks, etc.)

In the case of capturing the form name on an ajax submission, once ajax has returned you can capture the form name via jQuery and call your Direct Call Rule.

Within the custom code of that rule you should then be able to set eVar 1 with the form name.

The trick is to call the direct call rule after ajax has returned and then within the custom code, grab the form name and set eVar 1.

Hope this helps.